# Passing callback function to thread in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, c++-cli

Some context: I know basic C++. For the first time, I'm trying to create a GUI application in Visual Studio using C++/CLI. However, I can't find much answers online about the latter.

I've got two classes: `MyForm`, the main class corresponding to a Windows Form, and `OtherClass`. `MyForm`has an object of type `OtherClass` as a member. A function of `MyForm`, in this example `myButton_Click`, initializes this object and calls one of its function in a thread:

```
using namespace System::Threading;

ref class MyForm;
ref class OtherClass;

public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
    public:

    //...

    private:
        OtherClass^ o;

        System::Void myButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             //When the button is clicked, start a thread with o->foo
             o = gcnew OtherClass;
             Thread^ testThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o, &OtherClass::foo));
             newThread->Start();

        }



};
```

---

```
ref class OtherClass {
    public:
        void foo() {
            //Do some work;
        }
};
```

This seems to be working, so far. What I want is to **pass some kind of callback function from `MyClass` to `o->foo`** to update the UI with values from `foo` while it's running.

What's the best way to do this? Simply passing function pointers doesn't work because of CLI.

Comment: Most likely [a delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the way to go, but I can't find a way to use them across multiple files. If I try to declare the delegate in both header files, I get a redefinition error (duh). If I declare the delegate in only one of the files, I get a unknown identifier error in the other file. And there does not seem to be a way to forward-declare the delegate in that file.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147523/7034621) suggests declaring delegate in stdafx.h

Comment: I found this earlier, but didn't pursue it. Now I've got it working though. Thanks again! I'll write up a short answer for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. However, as pointed out by @Hans Passant, this is pretty much mimicking the behavior of a `BackgroundWorker`. Anyway, below is the answer to the top question, without using a `BackgroundWorker`. It feels not very clean, though.

---

As pointed by @orhtej2, [a `delegate` is what's needed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx). For both of the above header files to recognize it, I had to declare the delegate in `stdafx.h` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005892/how-do-i-forward-declare-a-delegate-in-c-cli/1147523#1147523)), for example like this:

```
delegate void aFancyDelegate(System::String^);
```

I then passed such a delegate to the constructor of OtherClass, so the object initialization line in `MyForm` changed from

```
o = gcnew OtherClass;
```

to

```
aFancyDelegate^ del = gcnew aFancyDelegate(this, &MyForm::callbackFunction);
o = gcnew OtherClass(del);
```

.

Lastly, to be able to update UI elements from `callbackFunction`, even if it was called from another thread, it had to include something like this, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116993/1798629):

```
void callbackFunction(String^ msg) {

            //Make sure were editing from the right thread
            if (this->txtBox_Log->InvokeRequired) {
                aFancyDelegate^ d =
                    gcnew aFancyDelegate(this, &MyForm::callbackFunction);
                this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { msg });
                return;
            }

            //Update the UI and stuff here.
            //...
        }
```

Comment: You are re-inventing the BackgroundWorker class.  Nobody can tell if that was intentional, but it doesn't exactly look like it.

Comment: I've never used a BackgroundWorker before. I'll read into it, thanks!

Comment: Update: a BackgroundWorker was exactly what I needed. Thanks again!